# Função JS não realiza calculo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei um formulário que é adicionado a pagina através de um botão. Usei JS para criar o formulário a ser adicionado. O problema é que tenho dois campos um de valor e outro de horas, para contabilizar o valor da hora trabalhada. 
Então apliquei nos input que recebem o dado de valor e hora a função:

```
onblur="value();".
```

Valor:

```
input name="horas" id="horas" type="text" value="" onblur="value();" class="form-control"
```

Hora:

```
input name="valor" id="valor" type="text" value="" onblur="value();" class="form-control
```

Essa função value é a seguinte:

```
function value(){  
  var val= $("input[name*='valor]']").maskMoney('unmasked')[0];    
  var hs= Number($("input[name*='horas']").val());  
  var resul= (hours == 0 ? 0 : val/hs);  
  $('#resulVal').val(resulVal.toFixed(2).replace('.', ','));  
}
```

Quando adiciono apenas UM FORMULÁRIO, a função realiza a conta. 
Mas ao adicionar mais de um formulário os seguintes não fazem a conta, é como se a função não fosse ativada para os demais. O que fazer?

Comment: Quando você diz "não realiza a conta", da algum erro? ou simplesmente nao aparece o que você queria?

Comment: Acredito que deve ter algo haver com o `name` ou o `id` do elemento

Comment: Amigo, este _"um formulario"_, você adicionou manipulando o DOM com javascript também ? Se você fizer um exemplo no JSFiddle fica mais facil para ajudarmos. Mas uma coisa que pode acontecer é em relação aos formularios por serem adicionados dinamicamente. Antes no JQuery havia uma função chamada $.live que tratava eventos em elementos dinamicos, hoje existe uma outra maneira de tratar esses eventos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo o que notei a sua pagina tem n formularios com uma estrutura semelhante a seguinte:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input name="horas" type="text" onblur="value();" />
    <input name="valor" type="text" onblur="value();" />
    <input name="resulVal" type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input name="horas" type="text" onblur="value();" />
    <input name="valor" type="text" onblur="value();" />
    <input name="resulVal" type="text" />
</form>
...
<form id="formN">
    <input name="horas" type="text" onblur="value();" />
    <input name="valor" type="text" onblur="value();" />
    <input name="resulVal" type="text" />
</form>
```

neste caso, na hora de fazer a seleção, é importante definir um escopo, neste caso o escopo é o form mais proximo, ou seja o form à que o input pertence.

```
function value(){  
    var elem = $(this);
    var escopo = elem.closest("form");
    var input = {
        valor: $("input[name='valor']", escopo),
        horas: $("input[name='horas']", escopo),
        result: $("input[name='resulVal']", escopo)
    };

    var valor = input.valor.maskMoney('unmasked')[0];    
    var horas = Number(input.horas.val());  
    var result = (horas == 0 ? 0 : valor/horas);  
    input.result.val(result.toFixed(2).replace('.', ','));  
}
```

de forma opcional, é interessante você registrar o evento atraves do `.on()` do jQuery, ao invés de faze-lo de forma inline:

```
$(document).on("blur", "input[name='valor'], input[name='horas']", function (){  
    var elem = $(this);
    var escopo = elem.closest("form");
    var input = {
        valor: $("input[name='valor']", escopo),
        horas: $("input[name='horas']", escopo),
        result: $("input[name='resulVal']", escopo)
    };

    var valor = input.valor.maskMoney('unmasked')[0];    
    var horas = Number(input.horas.val());  
    var result = (horas == 0 ? 0 : valor/horas);  
    input.result.val(result.toFixed(2).replace('.', ','));  
})
```

P.S: como você está adicionando estes formularios de forma dinamica, aconselho você não atribuir um id aos inputs, ou pelo menos colocar algum prefixo (assim como fiz com os `form`), lembre-se que o id deve ser unico.